# Getting vine thumbnail

Tags: php, thumbnails, vine

I often try some code in online php editor so I don't have to upload files to my server or check it offline in browser.

I have this code that works in online editor:

```
   function get_vine_thumbnail( $id )
{
  $vine = file_get_contents("http://vine.co/v/{$id}");
    preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $vine, $matches);

    return ($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;
}

 $vine = "OBWu9Mmmujm";

echo get_vine_thumbnail($vine);
```

But when I upload it to my server it doesn't work anymore. Of course this shows only link to thumbnail. Anyone know what is the problem?

EDIT-SOLUTION: Go to your web hosting control panel, go to CGI and Scripted Language Support, select PHP Scripting and change allow_url_fopen = Off to allow_url_fopen = On.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work fine

```
   function get_vine_thumbnail( $id )
{
  $vine = file_get_contents("http://vine.co/v/{$id}");
    preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $vine, $matches);

    return ($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;
}

 $vine = "OBWu9Mmmujm";

echo '<img src="'.get_vine_thumbnail($vine).'"/>';
```

Comment: I know, when I try it in online editor it works perfectly, but when I upload it to my server it doesn't work. I created new file, cause maybe first one was corrupted, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: So I seem to only ever get the default vine homepage, regardless of which video URL I try to parse. any thoughts?